# tab separator in sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, tabs, separator

How do you specify a tab separator in a table in sqlite3 for data import? That is:

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('mydatabase.db')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE mytable(c1 INT, c2 REAL);")
```

at this point I'd need to specify the tab separator just like you'd type .separator "\t" inside Sqlite after creating the table. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, what do you need the tab for? As a value in a row?

Comment: That depends on what code you're using to import. (Hint: the `sqlite3` module doesn't have any.)

Comment: @ CL: you're saying that sqlite3 doesnt have a command that specifies the tabular format of the file to be imported and so one is bound to accept the default csv format one? Like i thought.